# What to do about autofocus problems on a brand new SLR?

Tags: nikon, autofocus, troubleshooting

I'm having an autofocus problem with my new D5300: I've tested with both the 18-55 kit lens and the 50mm 1.8 AF-S, but it won't always autofocus. I have tested in good light conditions, with different kinds of surfaces to focus on, at good range. If I unmount and remount the lens, it will sometimes start AF, and also sometimes continue to work flawless and fast.

Everything is brand new - this is my first real try at using a DSLR.

Should I clean connectors, or contact the store I bought it from and/or Nikon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the face of it, this does sound very much like a problem with your camera - you've tested it with two lenses so it's (almost certainly) not the lens, and you've shown it's intermittent by unmounting and mounting the lens. Given that, my recommendations would be:

- If you've got any friends / co-workers / acquaintances with SLRs, ask them to have a quick look at the camera. I think it's pretty unlikely, but they may point out something you're doing wrong.
- Contact the store you bought it from. The product is most likely faulty, so you want them to get you a working camera (preferably a replacement rather than repair in order to get you up and running as quick as possible).
- If the store won't help (at least in the UK, they'd legally have to), contact Nikon under your warranty.

I wouldn't recommend a beginner trying to clean any contacts - there's just a bit too much chance of things going wrong, at which point you may not be able to get your money back from the store and/or Nikon.

Comment: I have been in contact with Nikon (through the store), who will take a look at it (probably repair/exchange as it is faulty).
I tried my lens at another house (D5300), and two other lenses at my house. My house seems to be the problem.

Comment: Late update: They changed the connectors.
Thank you for your input!